# Unable to update subdocument with mongoose expressjs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am unable to update the sub-document using mongoose express

```
model.update({ _id: _id),"company_offer.id": subdoc.id }, 
    {"$set": {
        "company_offer.$.candidate_accepted": "1"
    }}, 
    function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            return res.send({ message: err });
        }

        return res.send({ data: result, message: 'Data updated!' });
    }
);
```

Comment: What does you documents looks like. please provide that in the question itself.

Comment: Please format your question properly

Comment: I am pretty sure you are missing at least one parenthesis.

Comment: First of all there is syntax error in your update query.